# react native inAppBrowser cookies clearing

Tags: react-native, inappbrowser, react-native-inappbrowser-reborn

in our react-native app, we are using react-native-inappbrowser-reborn for opening some pages. For IOS it have ephemeralWebSession option which prevents re-use of cookies. But how to do same for Android? Login backend, we are using, returns previous session if user opens it second time (because of same cookies are send I guess). And I can`t find a way to clear them from app side.

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution? Having the same issue

Comment: Nop, not really. Workaround we do in one place is to open default browser with url. But it's a bit ugly..

Comment: I have managed to track the origin of this problem (on our side), it's that the session never dies, and has to be killed on our backend, this looks like a solution for us, but we have control over our backend and session, hope this might help you